# Mongoose array object maxlength validation not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the schema below that is allowing me to create a user with a badge of "1234567" for an existing app. I expected to receive a validation error b/c of the maxlength validation.

Is there something wrong with my schema?

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var appSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        settings: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        user: [{
          badge: {
            type: String,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 5
          }
        }]
    });

    // Export the schema for the app to use
    return db.model('apps', appSchema);
}
```

I'm trying to use

```
apps.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {user: req.body.user}}, {runValidators: true},callback());
```

to add a new user record to the array in an app document.

Answer (score 1):

Validators will only [work on updates for $set and $unset operations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-on-specified-paths), so I believe you will have to validate manually before the update in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As from docs, [mongoose requires an Schema to validate nested objects](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#required-validators-on-nested-objects).

so your schema should be defined as such.

Can you try using the following definition instead?

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    badge: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 5
    }
});

var appSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    settings: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    user: [userSchema]
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. This is how i'm trying to insert a user record to an existing app: `apps.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {user: req.body.user}}, {runValidators: true},callback());`